# Client -Breeze, create complex-type property

Tags: javascript, breeze

I work in Durandal-project and use Breeze-Entities.

In Breeze, you an give to entity-type, complex-type property.

I did it at server-breeze entities, but don't know how to do it in client-entity.

Here is my code in server-entity:

```
      function addEmployeeType(store) {
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "EmployeeDTO",
            namespace: "myServer.Entities",
            autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
            dataProperties: {
                Emp_no: { dataType: DataType.Int32, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },
                employeeBaseData: {
                    name: "employeeBaseData",
                    complexTypeName: "EmployeeBaseDTO:#myServer.Entities",
                    isNullable: false,
                    isPartOfKey: false
                } 
        });
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("EmployeeDTO", null, employeeInit);
    }


    function addEmployeeBaseDataType(store) {
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "EmployeeBaseDTO",
            namespace: "myServer.Entities",
            isComplexType: true,
            dataProperties: {
                name: { dataType: DataType.String, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false, validators: [Validator.required(),validationHelper.numeric()] }
            }
        });
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor("EmployeeBaseDTO", null, null);
    }
```

here is my code which doesn't work- code of client side:

```
   function addReportType() {
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: 'Report',
            autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
            dataProperties: {
                key:{ dataType: DataType.Int32, isNullable: false, isPartOfKey: true },
                dateArea: {
                    name: "dateArea",
                    complexTypeName: "dateArea",
                    isNullable: false,
                    isPartOfKey: false
                }
            }
        });
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor('Report', null, ReportInit);

    }

 function addReportDateAreaType() {
        store.addEntityType({
            shortName: "dateArea",               
            isComplexType: true,
            dataProperties: {
                fromDate: { dataType: DataType.Date, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false },
                toDate: { dataType: DataType.Date, isNullable: true, isPartOfKey: false }
            }
        });
        store.registerEntityTypeCtor('dateArea', null, dateAreaInit);
    }
```

I understand that my code isn't correct.

When I try to create instance of the ReportType I accept : "Unable to get property '_createInstanceCore' of undefined or null reference".

So what is the correct way to create complex-type property for client-breeze entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add ':#' to the complexType name.
It means that insteed of writing:

```
   complexTypeName: "dateArea",
```

You need to write:

```
    complexTypeName: "dateArea:#",
```

Comment: Or, better, define the property `namespace: xxxx` for both the `Report` and `dataArea` types